# JAXB Annotations and SuperClass

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I'm trying to use JAXB annotations in a parent class so that all the sub classes can inherit them but I'm running into a marshaling error.  I don't get the below error when I include @XmlRootElement and @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) in the sub class

error:
HTTP Status 500 - Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/xml

```
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {

//class contents here
}

public class Child extends Parent{

//class contents here
}
```

Comment: What does the JAX-RS method annotated with `@GET` return `ArrayList<Parent>`, `ArrayList<Child>`, or `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to list all of your subclasses in [@XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) annotation of your parent class.